# Find duplicate patterns in each row and the count of repetition?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to implement it on unix platform. shell, tcsh or csh will be favorable.
Suppose I have the input data as below:-

```
a abc abc acd abc
b qwe qre wet dfe
c rte wet dfr wet
d tyr fre wer wty
```

and The output I want is as below:-

```
3 abc
0
2 wet
0
```

Comment: Are you asking us to write your source code?

Comment: What if there are more than one set of duplicates in a record?

Comment: No Dominique. I want to know if any one liner or one word which I am missing. Because as per my knowledge, uniq command could help me if the issue was in coloumn but not in row.

Comment: @arpitjain, It would be helpful if you could post what have you tried so far, and the issue you are facing.

Comment: Where are the data? In a file?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe. Yes, the data is in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
cut -d' ' -f2- yourFile | while read line; do
    echo "$line" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | grep -v '^ *1' || echo 0;
done | sed 's/^ *//'
```

The idea is to transform the spaces into newlines such that `uniq` etc. can be used to analyze every line as a sequence of lines.

Comment: hi. "While read line" is not working.

Comment: Could yoube more specific?

Comment: hi, Thanx. This logic helped me to find out the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      ++freq[$i]
   s = ""
   for (i in freq)
      if (freq[i] > 1)
         s = s freq[i] OFS i ORS
   printf "%s", (s == "" ? "0" ORS : s)
   delete freq
}' file
```

```
3 abc
0
2 wet
0
```

Comment: No Anubhava. this for loop is not getting run.

Comment: [Here is working demo of above code](https://ideone.com/hgzh4P)

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
cat file.txt | while read line; do echo $line | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq -c | sort -k2nr | awk 'END{print}'| awk '{ if ($1 == 1) print 0; else print $1, $2}'  ; done
```

With awk I can make more conditionals for output.